# PyTorch: 'ToTensor()' turns color image into 9 grayscale pictures

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have found that when I use 'ToTensor' to a images, one image becomes 9 displayed.I checked the official documents but couldn't find the reason. so why a picture become 9 pictures???questioon as the following figure.

```
a = plt.imread('test.jpg')
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
b = transform(a)
b = b.view(375,500,3)
plt.imshow(b)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `transforms.ToTensor()`, by default it changes the input arrays from HWC to CHW order. For plotting, you'll need to push back the channels to the last dimension.

```
plt.imshow(b.permute(2, 0, 1))
```